# Image classification using ResNet-50

Tags: image, classification, resnet

I try to train ResNet 50 for Image classification using this code: https://github.com/mlperf/training/blob/master/image_classification/tensorflow/official/resnet/imagenet_main.py, but in process i have error in line 322   seed = int(argv[1]) IndexError: list index out of range. How can I fix this error? I am using Tenserflow 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message `IndexError: list index out of range` suggests that the list `argv` has length < 2 (since index 1 is already out of bounds).

`sys.argv` contains the list of *argument values* that you pass on the command line. The first element, `argv[0]` is always the name of the script you invoke.
In your case this means that you did not pass any arguments.

So looking at the code, it tries to read - as the first command line option - a seed that it can use to initialise various random number generators (RNG) with.
So what you want to do is invoke your script with something like:

```
python imagenet_main.py r4nd0ms33d
```

where `r4nd0ms33d` is some random value.

Sometimes explicitly seeding the RNG with a fixed value can be useful, e.g. when you want your training results to be reproducable.

---

You can play around with this simple Python program:

```
import sys                                                                      

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    print(sys.argv)
```

Save it into `test.py` and see what it prints if you run it as `python test.py` versus `python test.py random` versus `python test.py random seed`